mod_rewrite append slash at the end, except if there was an equal sign in the URL
I like to enforce an ending slash at the end of my URLs, which I do with the following in my .htaccess file:
#append slash at end of URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

however this causes an issue if I happen to be placing something in a query string like:
https://www.mywebsite.com/regular/path/page=22/

How would this rewrite be modified so that it only appends this ending slash if there has not been an equals sign (=) in the visible URL such that I could end up with this:
https://www.mywebsite.com/regular/path/page=22

FURTHER CLARIFICATION (thank you @arkascha):
I think it will need to be done with %{THE_REQUEST} because there will always be a query string behind the scenes.  I am actually using much more complex rewrite rules to map complex query strings into something that looks more user-friendly.  My real urls work like this:
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/Php-File-Name/action/filter=all

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.+)  /$2.php?CustomerSlug=$1&action=$3&$4 [NC,L]

Any of these URLs are great (notice that the first two do NOT end with a slash)...I only need to skip the ending slash when there is something in the final position, as it gets picked up as a part of the variable value in the query string
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/Php-File-Name/action/filter=all&value=4&color=blue
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/Php-File-Name/action/filter=all
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/Php-File-Name/action/
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/Php-File-Name/
https://www.mywebsite.com/CustomerSlug/
https://www.mywebsite.com/


"however this causes an issue if I happen to be placing something in a query string like: https://www.mywebsite.com/regular/path/page=22/" - there is no query string in that URL, you simply added a path component that happens to contain a = character.

@CBroe There IS a query string here, in the underlying interpretation, as this path is converted by the mod_rewrite rule to https://www.mywebsite.com/path.php?CustomerSlug=regular&action=&page=22 (although in your example, the action element is missing, so that was not a valid URL in my system)

The URLs you now added with your update to the question are highly exotic. I am not even sure if they are valid in the strict sense though this probably will work. The ampersand ("&") and the equal sign ("=") will be percent encoded when requested, you need to take that into account. From a technical point of view these URLs do not have a query string at all, but just a path component. Simply because there is no question mark in them. So a simple rewrite rule based on %{REQUEST_URI} will certainly be suitable.

Well, you need to test if the requested URL has a query string. That probably would be a simple approach:
#append slash at end of URLs
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,QSA]

This will prevent the application of the RewriteRule if there is anything in the query string. Note that is not formally exactly "if there is a question mark", the query string might be empty, yet the question mark might have been added. It is a question of the requesting client (the browser) if it is sent then, so there is not reliable way to determine that. It would be pointless anyway, so I'd say you can safely ignore that case. If you do want to go down that path you'd have to test against the %{THE_REQUEST} variable instead. See the documentation for details about that.
I wonder however why you don't want a trailing slash if there is a query string. In my eyes that breaks the logic.
Also a hint for your existing RewriteCond: keep in mind that %{REQUEST_URI} always contains the absolute path of the requested URL. So it can never be empty, it will always contain a trailing slash. Which is why your last option in the pattern (^$) will never match.

I think it will need to be done with %{THE_REQUEST} because there will always be a query string behind the scenes.  I added some more detail and corrected a typo (it is equal sign, not question mark)
